# Append dynamically created headers to div from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I figured out how to create headers and append it to my html div, but if I press the button to create and append twice, it overwrites the other one. I want it so if I press the button twice, the new header will appear underneath, and not overwrite.

```
HTML
<div class="tools">
        <asp:Button ID="HeaderOne" class="tool" runat="server" Text="Header 1" Height="35px" Width="100px" OnClick="HeaderOne_Click" /> <br />
        <asp:Button ID="HeaderTwo" class="tool" runat="server" Text="Header 2" Height="35px" Width="100px" OnClick="HeaderTwo_Click" /> <br />
        <asp:Button ID="HeaderThree" class="tool" runat="server" Text="Header 3" Height="35px" Width="100px" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="HeaderFour" class="tool" runat="server" Text="Header 4" Height="35px" Width="100px" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="HeaderFive" class="tool" runat="server" Text="Header 5" Height="35px" Width="100px" /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="HeaderSix" class="tool" runat="server" Text="Header 6" Height="35px" Width="100px" /><br />
    </div>
    <div runat="server" class="emailPreview" id="emailPreview">

    </div>

C#
protected void HeaderOne_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        emailPreview.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<label class='labelHeader1' contentEditable=true>"));
        emailPreview.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Header 1"));
        emailPreview.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</label>"));
    }
    protected void HeaderTwo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        emailPreview.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<label class='labelHeader2' contentEditable=true>"));
        emailPreview.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("Header 2"));
        emailPreview.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</label>"));
    }
```

Comment: Asp.net postback do not work they way you think they do since by default web is stateless. Meaning that when a postback happens (button is clicked) all your dynamically inserted controls will disappear. I would suggest starting with this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On asp.net postback, all of the dynamically added controls disappear.
There are two ways to solve this.

***First method*** -
Save a list of dynamically added controls in your `Session`,
each render you should check

```
 if (IsPostBack)
```

and if it is a postback, render all the controls in the list you saved to the session before appending new ones.

***Second method*** -
You can bind an onclick event with javascript and add the elements from there.
this method will not require a refresh to the page (postback) and will not delete/overwrite the elements you added previously